# Saved picture has noise added

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

When matplotlib's pyplot stores pictures that are created by `imshow()`, sometimes the saved pdf does look different from the one open in the interactive console. Not with respect to dimensions, which can be caused by `tight_layout()`, but with respect to additional noise.

**This question is not about the following example, but rather more broadly. The pictures are only here to demonstrate what I mean by noise.**

Interactive console:

[image: Picture in interactive console]

Stored pdf:

[image: Picture, stored as pdf]

What are typical reasons for why the stored pdf would differ in this way from the interactive console?

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `interpolation=None` parameter. The problem is discussed more in detail here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2972/